# Хранение логических флагов в одном символе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Идея такая, вместо создания разных столбцов в БД для флагов типо "не показывать больше подсказки по сайту, аккаунт подтверждён" и т.п. выделить один столбец длинной в бит 16 (2 символа) и раскладывать его на биты дабы экономить ресурсы

На сколько это рационально? Или я параноик и слишком переработал с микроконтроллерами?

Comment: Вы параноик, лучше разбейте на столбцы иначе потом сделать например выборку всех не подтвержденных аккунтов будет большой проблемой.

Comment: [The SET Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MySQL есть побитовые операции и их можно использовать, только если у Вас есть в этом реальная необходимость (например, крайне ограничена память).

В остальных случаях лучше использовать битовые поля под каждый отдельный признак.
Это упростит и сопровождение кода и, более того, ускорит работу, если вдруг понадобится выбирать данные по этим признакам, т.к. с одним INT для набора признаков Вы уже не сможете использовать индексы.

Comment: Я точно уверен, что выборки по этому полю не будет

Comment: Оно будет использоваться для разных подсказок, для кнопок типо "больше не показывать данное сообщение"

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL есть тип данный BIT или BOOLEAN для таких флагов и это будет сопровождаемая БД и код.
Если сделать хранение опций в виде битов в INT или более, то сопровождаемость кода резко падает. Обычно экономия места или вычислительных ресурсов того не стоит.